# prove that null set product $R^n$ is of measure zero

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be a set of measure zero. I want to prove that the Cartesian product of $E$ and $R^n$ is also of measure zero.

I thought of maybe using intervals to cover the product, as I know $E$ is of measure zero, but I couldn't really work it out.

Comment: You have not said where $E$ is and w.r.t. what measure it has measure $0$. If it has measure $0$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on an Euclidean space then this is an immediate application of Fubini's Theorem

Comment: It is in the space $R^m$. Could you show how do you use Fubini's theorem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Tonellis theorem for non-negetive functions:
$$\lambda^{m + n}(E \times \mathbb{R}^n) = \int_{E \times \mathbb{R}^n} d \lambda^{m+n}(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_E d\lambda^m(x) d\lambda^n(y) = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me